# Is it possible to remove height and width attributes from oEmbed video embeds

Tags: oembed

I was wondering if it's possible to use oEmbed that is built into the core of WP to display video embeds but somehow remove the height and width attritbutes in the output? I know the functions exist in media.php but I don't want to mess with the core.

The reason I ask is that we're developing a theme for a client which using a fluid grid framework and any image/video with specified height and width attributes means they don't scale with the grid in smaller viewports - or there may be a way to make this work?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The output of the oEmbed call is filtered through `oembed_result` and then cached in the database. Every time the content is displayed, the output is filtered again through `embed_oembed_html`. So you can add a filter in either of these places that checks for `width` and `height` attributes and removes them. Of course, since the code comes from the embed sources, you can't always be sure what the formatting will look like. The second argument to both filters is the embed URL, you can check that to differentiate your handling ("if it's from YouTube do this, if it's from Flickr do that, ...").

Comment: Thanks Jan, so would something along the lines of this be correct?`code`

function strip_attributes($oembvideo) {
$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();
$patterns[] = '<iframe height=""';
$patterns[] = '<iframe width=""';

$replacements[] = '<iframe height=""';
$replacements[] = '<iframe width=""';

return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $oembvideo);

 return $oembvideo;
}
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'stripattributes');

Comment: @Mark-Fublo: That would be the idea, yes. Of course, not every video is returned in an iframe, and maybe there are other parameters that define the size of the player. You'll have to try it and see what works. Post it back as an answer, it could be useful for others!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the client is only using Vimeo in this instance, so I'll see what I can work out and see if I can get it working

Comment: I can't seem to paste the code from here http://wp-snippets.com/adjust-vimeo-auto-embed-size/ into this comment, too big..

Comment: Anyway, I can edit the height and width to output as nothing. Though it displays the video at the incorrect size. Realistically a solution to have full width video at all sizes of the viewport is what I am after - If it can be done at all?

Comment: @Mark-Fublo: I suggest you first try it in a static page: just embed the Vimeo code, and edit it until it scales well. If you have achieved that, write your code so that it changes the input to that output.